# Swift 3 Sprite Node Contact / Collision not behaving properly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skspritenode

**What I have now**: Most of my current Sprite Node collisions work the way they should, except for the boxNode coming in contact with the floorNode. I have 3 sprite nodes: a floorNode, playerNode, and boxNode. The playerNode bounces in the air when the user taps the screen, and the boxNode(s)spawn from the ceiling and fall until coming in contact with the floorNode.

**The Problem**: The collision that Im having trouble with is when the boxNode collides with the floorNode. The game currently ends when the boxNode comes in contact with the floorNode, when all that should happen is the boxNode disappears when colliding with the floorNode.

playerNode collides with floorNode = game over

boxNode collides with playerNode = game over

boxNode collides with floorNode = (The game ends when this collision occurs) Shouldn't cause the game to end.

**This is my current code**:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import SceneKit
import Foundation
import CoreData
import GameplayKitstruct

ColliderType {

static let blueBallCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
static let floorNode: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
static let firstBody: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
static let secondBody: UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
static let boxNodeCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 4

}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

floorNode.contactTestBitMask = 0
floorNode.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.floorNodeCategory
floorNode.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.playerNodeCategory | ColliderType.boxNodeCategory
self.physicsBody = floorNode
self.physicsBody?.friction = 0

playerNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.playerNodeCategory
playerNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
playerNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.floorNodeCategory

boxNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.boxNodeCategory
boxNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.playerNodeCategory | ColliderType.floorNodeCategory
boxNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0



func didBegin(_ contact:SKPhysicsContact) {

              let firstBody = contact.bodyA
              let secondBody = contact.bodyB


if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.playerNodeCategory || secondBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.boxNodeCategory{

                self.boxNode.removeFromParent()

                gameOver = true
                self.speed = 0
                timer.invalidate()


}else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.floorNodeCategory || secondBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.floorNodeCategory {

                gameOver = true
                self.speed = 0
                timer.invalidate()

}else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.boxNodeCategory || secondBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.floorNodeCategory{


                self.boxNode.removeFromParent()



}else if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.boxNodeCategory{

                contact.bodyA.node!.removeFromParent()

}else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.boxNodeCategory{

                contact.bodyB.node!.removeFromParent()

                gameOver = true
                self.speed = 0
                timer.invalidate()


}

}

}
```

Comment: Your code snippet is confusing as the indents are messed up (possibly when you copied it) but also it looks partial. Please post your full contact handling delegate method, I.e. func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {...

Comment: Hi @AliBeadle, I updated my code and fixed the indentations, so hopefully now its a bit easier to read. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that you have not accounted properly for the fact that the method didBegin(contact:) bodyA and bodyB could be in either order. For example if physics body X collides with physics body Y, the method didBegun(contact:) could be called with bodyA=X and bodyB=Y **or** bodyA=Y and bodyB=X. Your code needs to account for that and currently it does not.

Specifically the case where bodyA is the floor and bodyB is the box: this will fail all except your last condition - which ends the game.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have been busier than usual at work. Would it be possible to create more contact bodies? Ex: let  thirdBody = contact.bodyC. I am still learning swift, is there a way to specifically assign bodyA and bodyB for a specific case / condition?

Comment: @p.dane I am not quite sure I understand. Note that Swift is just the language. The sprites, physics bodies etc. are provided by SpriteKit, an API independent of the Swift language. Each Sprite can have its own physics body. You can have as many sprites (with physics bodies) as you like. Each physics body has a category - the category is a 32 bit mask so you can have up to 32 different categories.

Comment: I am sorry for any confusion that I may have caused. You had mentioned that bodyA and bodyB could be in either order. But in this case, bodyA needs to be assigned to the floorNode and bodyB assigned to the boxNode. Instead of having the bodies be in either order, is there a way to assign a body to a specific node?

Comment: I will edit my answer to clarify - I meant in the method didBegin(contact:) that bodyA and bodyB could be either way around.

Comment: I am sorry for the delayed response, work has been very busy. Your updated answer makes a lot more sense to me, however when I implemented what you had advised into my code, it didn't really fix the problem. For whatever reason, whenever I add in  " else-if " statements or lines of code into the didBegin(contact:) method, the code I add doesn't seem to work. I will update my original code above soon.